# Who was involved in the casting for the Mickey Mouse Club in the early 1990s?

Tags: casting

Someone on that show seems to have had a real eye for talent and star potential even in singers/actors that were still children. I don't know it was the casting director, a subordinate, a producer, or someone else. They cast Keri Russell in 1991 and Justin Timberlake, Britney Spears, Christina Aguilera, and Ryan Gosling in 1993.

Comment: "Who did the casting" is not any different than "who starred in..." It's off topic. This information is simple to obtain by using IMDb. For more information, see [Meta](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/55/16420).

Comment: Just because someone is listed as the the casting director doesn't mean they are the one that spotted the talent. It could have been a subordinate or a producer on the show that insisted these particular kids should be on the show.

Comment: This information is still on IMDb. The **only** other person listed in "casting" is Patricia Troy. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096641/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast If you really want some sort of in-depth expose of who actually did the casting because you doubt that Matt Casella or Patricia Troy did the work, then you'll need to clarify that in your question and explain why it matters.

Comment: That is why I said somone on the show had a real eye for talent, not that the casting directory had a real eye for talent. The credits only give part of the story. Or don't you think producers, network executives, etc. have a big influence over casting?

Comment: I'm sorry but you really can't expect people to read between the lines and interpret your question. You need to *explain* your question very clearly, particularly when it's at risk of being closed for being off topic. If you won't do any work, please don't expect us to. You still haven't explained why you think Matt Casella didn't honestly discover all of these kids.

Comment: When did I say that he didn't discover these kids? I just said that just because he is credited as casting director doesn't necessarily mean that he did. So you can't read between the lines for "someone had an eye for talent" But you are reading between the lines that questioning who had the eye means I'm saying he didn't have the eye for talent.

Comment: If you want to know who "had a real eye for talent" and you want to argue that this is on topic, the **only** way this is on topic is if you think for some reason that the person credited with casting this talent is **not** the person who did it. Otherwise, the information is on IMDb and is off topic here. So, something like "IMDb credits Matt Casella and Patricia Troy with the casting of *The New Mickey Mouse Club* in the 90s. Are they really the only people involved in discovering this talent?"

Comment: User Matt Casella tried to add this comment, but they added it to my question instead of as a comment: Take it from me, I was the guy that found all the kids. From Ryan (Montreal) to Keri (Denver) to Justin (Nashville), Britney (Atlanta), Christina (Pittsburgh), JC Chasez in DC. Two of them are actually nominated for Academy Awards this year and I couldn't be more proud of Justin and Ryan along with all of the kids that I found for that show. Chase, Tiff, TJ, Marc, Rhona, Dale, Tony, I could go on but who knows if this will even get posted here. Anyway, Just wanted to set the record straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to IMDB it was [**Matt Casella**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0143294/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm)

> As Casting Director for The Walt Disney Company and Jeffrey Katzenberg, Matt Casella auditioned over 85,000 kids during 1988-1994 for "The All New Mickey Mouse Club". From these auditions, which he did by holding open calls throughout the United States and Canada, Matt discovered, directed and launched the careers of: Justin Timberlake, Ryan Gosling, Britney Spears, Christina Aguilera, Keri Russell, JC Chasez and Tony Lucca, among others.

In an [**interview**](http://www.nydailynews.com/archives/nydn-features/mouse-roared-mickey-tv-club-helped-spawn-series-stars-article-1.894181) Casella said.

> "I knew how special these kids were when I saw them," says Casella, **who saw 20,000 kids during four years of auditions.** "There was sort of an eagerness and a sparkle in their eye that said, 'I want it.

Tony Lucca (an ex-Mouse Clubber) [**said**](http://blogs.mcall.com/lehighvalleymusic/2012/05/interviewing-tony-lucca-the-voices-polarizing-third-place-finisher.html)

> “...But Matt Casella, the casting director, has an impeccable eye for talent. He really bats 1.000. There were a  couple of times maybe, where he was off [laughs] but he cast some pretty big projects  over the years, but the Mouse Club was definitely his crowning achievement in that he identified something in all of us that he just see in other people. He realized that there was an inherent passion and desire and ability in all of us.

Comment: Thank you for adding the interview excerpts. They seem to confirm that the casting director was the one with the eye for talent.